# Help with car movie/DVD player - Invision Generation

Tags: audio

Our "Invision Generation Series" DVD player (installed by the dealer in our '08 Toyota Highlander) plays some DVDs just fine, but for many others, it doesn't get past the initial previews. It has extra trouble with Disney movies (of course, the very ones our kids want to watch).

I wondered if a firmware upgrade might do the trick, as the unit allows connecting USB. But no mention of this in the manual, or on the mfr's website.

Any thoughts/suggestions? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing we did at the dealer was send them to the radio shop authorized by the manufacturer. You might try calling the dealer in your area and ask who they send their radios too. We sent ours to Downtown Radio Service in Raleigh NC